# Estrutura de decisão, como saber qual utilizar?

Tags: jquery, lógica

Sobre boa prática de lógica:

Tenho uma *DropDownList* com 8 valores e dependendo do que for selecionado irá adicionar/remover componentes de uma página `html`, onde os mesmo são manipulados via `jQuery`

Agora minha dúvida é, qual seria a melhor forma(caso existe uma) de separar os valores dessa listagem ? Pensei em 3 formas:

> **Switch Case**
>
> **String.Compare**
>
> **If Else IF**

Exemplo

```
  $("#<%=ddlListagens.ClientID%>").change(function () {
                    var vlr = $("#<%=ddlListagens.ClientID%>").val();
                    if (vlr == "RC") {
                        $("#ciclo").show(500);
                        $("#Situacao").hide(500);
                        $("#empresa").hide(500);
                        $("#meses").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=ddlDataDe.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=txtDataIni.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=txtDataFim.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=txtGrupoFat.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=txtCodCli.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=txtDSini.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=txtDSfim.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=Label5.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=ddlEmpFim.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=ddlEmpIni.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=ddlTipoReg.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=ddlMeses.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=ddlDS.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=ddlOrdenacao.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=Label22.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=Label1.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=Label19.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=Label12.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=Label2.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=btnImpListagem.ClientID%>").hide(500);
                        $("#<%=btnImpListaXLS.ClientID%>").show(500);

                    }
```

Comment: Na minha opinião, um if simples para cada bloco estaria bom demais, sem `if else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor, como a decisão irá girar em torno de um elemento apenas `dropdown`, para essa situação, o mais adequado seria usar o `switch`. Um exemplo:

```js
$('#selecao').change(function(){
    switch($('#selecao option:selected').val()){
        case 'op1' : alert('Opção 1 escolhida!')
        break;
        case 'op2' : alert('Opção 2 escolhida!')
        break;
        case 'op3' : alert('Opção 3 escolhida!')
        break;
        case 'op4' : alert('Opção 4 escolhida!')
        break;
        case 'op5' : alert('Opção 5 escolhida!')
        break;
        default: alert('nenhuma opção selecionada!')
   }
});
```

```html
<select id="selecao">
  <option > Selecione uma opção </option>
  <option value="op1"> Opção 1 </option>
  <option value="op2"> Opção 2 </option>
  <option value="op3"> Opção 3 </option>
  <option value="op4"> Opção 4 </option>
  <option value="op5"> Opção 5 </option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Nesse exemplo, eu capturo o `value` do `option` selecionado e faço as ações que eu precisar.